# Strange problem with auto reboots

Tags: kubuntu, crash, reboot

I have a really strange problem. 2 days ago my Kubuntu suddenly rebooted, without any kind of freeze or something. After that, it auto reboots all the time. Of course, I started to think about whether I modified something or not.
I thought it was because of some driver, so I tried to uninstall Nvidia's one, but after reboot, I can't even login now. It reboots now on login screen...

That's not the strangest thing. I get Manjaro to my flash drive and tried to boot it up via Manjaro's live cd.
It loaded but there are specific files and when I open them it auto reboots  (did that even while it running on live)...
(opening exactly the same file (it's an image btw) on my Laptop (running Kubuntu as well) is OK and the system is not crashing).

Is that some kind of hardware issue? I have never experienced such problems before. Another thing: I have Windows 10 as a secondary OS. I tried to switch to it for some time, played some heavy games, etc - zero crashes/reboots.

Also, when I booted via Manjaro's live cd I noticed errors like that "mce: [hardware error]: cpu 10 machine check 0 bank "
I'm really confused. Am I experiencing a hardware issue or not, because it looks like Windows is running fine.
Tried to check my RAM using memtest. It's ok, all 4 passes ended without any errors.

I would be really happy to get some help because I'm struggling with that over it for 3 days and I started to get upset.

Comment: Have you tried to boot up an older kernel?

Comment: Yes. Actually, it auto reboot on windows now (it's just less often). I think it's hardware issue now. I'll warranty return my MB and CPU.
Linux write these lines in the journalctl: hunter-pc kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
hunter-pc kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 10: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: baa0000000000118